# Writing bytes without padding

Tags: python, bit

Given these 2 numbers (milliseconds since Unix epoch), 1656773855233 and 1656773888716, I'm trying to write them to a binary object. The kicker is that I want to write them to a 11 byte object.

If I accept that the timestamps can only represent dates before September 7th 2039, the numbers should each fit within 41bits. 2 41bit numbers fits within 88bit (11bytes) with 6 bits in excess.

I've tried the following python code, as a (rather naive) way to achieve this:

```
receive_time=1656773855233
event_time=1656773888716

with open("test.bin", "wb") as f:
    f.write(receive_time.to_bytes(6, "big"))
    f.write(event_time.to_bytes(6, "big"))

print(f"{receive_time:08b}")
print(f"{event_time:08b}")

with open("test.bin", "rb") as f:
    a = f.read()
    print(" ".join(f"{byte:08b}" for byte in a))
```

The output of the code very clearly shows that the `test.bin` file is 12 bytes, because each timestamp is padded with 7 0's when converted to bytes.

How would I go about writing the timestamps to `test.bin` without padding them individually?

The end result should be something like `0000001100000011011111101101010110010000000000111000000110111111011010110100101011001100` or `3037ED5900381BF6B4ACC`

EDIT: Question originally mentioned that a 41bit number could only represent dates before May 15th, 2109 if that number represented milliseconds since the Unix epoch. That is wrong, as interjay correctly pointed out, a 41bit number would only represent 69,7 years and the max date would thus be September 7th, 2039. A 42bit number, however, can represent a number that represents dates before May 15th, 2109.

Comment: 2**41 milliseconds is 69.7 years, so your dates will only go up to 2039 if unsigned, or 2004 if signed.

Comment: Do you really need millisecond precision? If two-miliseconds precision is good enough, you could store each in five bytes.

Comment: Maybe you can store the first time and a difference, where the difference will likely be smaller and take less space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a bit shift to combine both times into the same int, before converting that to `bytes`:

```
x = (receive_time << 41) + event_time
b = x.to_bytes(11, 'big')
with open("test.bin", "wb") as f:
    f.write(b)
```

Comment: Thank you! I had a feeling that bit shifting would be required, but I have not had to deal with these kind of problems for a decade, so couldn't wrap my head around it!